# Unit testing a binary format reader in C

Tags: c, stream, binary-data

I am writing a C library that reads a binary file format. I don't control the binary format; it's produced by a proprietary data acquisition program and is relatively complicated. As it is one of my first forays into C programming and binary file parsing, I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to structure the code for testing and portability.

For testing purposes, I thought the easiest course of action was to build the library to read an arbitrary byte stream. But I ended up implementing a *stream* data type that encapsulates the type of stream (`memstream`, `filestream`, etc). The interface has functions like `stream_read_uint8` such that the client code doesn't have to know anything about where the bytes are coming from. My tests are against a `memstream`, and the `filestream` stuff is essentially just a wrapper around `FILE*` and `fread`, etc.

From an OOP perspective, I *think* this is a reasonable design. However, I get the feeling that I am stuffing the wrong paradigm into the language and ending up with overly abstracted, overly complicated code as a result.

So my question: is there a simpler, more idiomatic way to do binary format reading in plain C while preserving automated tests?

Note: I realize that `FILE*` is essentially an abstract stream interface. But the implementation of memory streams (`fmemopen`) is non-standard and I want Standard C for portability.

Comment: In my not so expert opinion, I think that as long as your encapsulation makes things _easier_ to use for your users and/or solves a problem, and the code is reasonably maintainable and straight-forward, you're probably alright.

Comment: @prelic, thanks, of course that makes sense. It is just that I am also using the project as a bit of a learning exercise, so I'm interested in C best practices and norms.

Comment: I have been involved in projects reading binary formats and this is the approach we used and was used by pre-existing programs -- reading X bits at a time, marking a placeholder in the buffer after the read, and returning the data as uint8_t*, letting the caller convert into whatever type is necessary.  Not an answer to your question, just a *me too* from experience.

Comment: I'd be more concerned not with how to read from a file (which at times can be a very important part too), but with actual testing of the reader. I'd want to feed it total garbage. I'd want to feed it intentionally altered and even corrupted input (with different probability, in different locations, different values, etc). I'd want to see if my test at least give me the full statement coverage of the reader's code. All that plus the reader never hanging or crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you described is a low-level I/O functionality.  Since `fmemopen()` is not 100% portable (off Linux, it creaks, I suspect), then you need to provide yourself with something portable that you write that is sufficiently close that you can use your surrogate functions (only) when necessary and use the native functions when possible.  Of course, you should be able to force the use of your functions even in your native habitat so that you can test your code.

This code can be tested with known data to ensure that you pick up all the characters in the input streams and can faithfully return them.  If the raw data is in a specific endian-ness, you can ensure that your 'larger' types — hypothetically, functions such as `stream_read-uint2()`, `stream_read_uint4()`, `stream_read_string()` etc — all behave appropriately.  For this phase, you don't really need the actual data; you can manufacture data to suit yourself and your testing.

Once you've got that in place, you will also need to write code for reading the data with the larger types, and ensuring that these higher level function actually can interpret the binary data accurately and invoke appropriate actions.  For this, you finally need examples of what the format supplied; up until this phase you probably could get away with data you manufactured.  But once you're reading the actual files, you need examples of those to work on.  Or you'll have to manufacture them from your understanding and test as best you can.  How easy this is depends on how clearly documented the binary format is.

---

One of the key testing and debugging tools will be canonical 'dump' functions that can present data for you.  The scheme I use is:

```
extern void dump_XyzType(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const XyzType *data);
```

The stream is self-evident; usually it is `stderr`, but by making it an argument, you can get the data to any open file.  The `tag` is included in the information printed; it should be unique to identify the location of call.  The last argument is a pointer to the data type.  You can analyze and print that.  You should take the opportunity to assert all validity checks that you can think of, to head off problems.

You can extend the interface with `, const char *file, int line, const char *func` and arrange to add `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__func__` to the calls.  I've never quite needed it, but if I were to do it, I'd use:

```
#define DUMP_XyzType(fp, tag, data) \
        dump_XyzType(fp, tag, data, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__)
```

As an example, I deal with a type DATETIME, so I have a function

```
extern void dump_datetime(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const ifx_dtime_t *dp);
```

One of the tests I was using this week could be persuaded to dump a datetime value, and it gave:

```
DATETIME: Input value -- address 0x7FFF2F27CAF0
Qualifier: 3594 -- type DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
DECIMAL: +20120913212219 -- address 0x7FFF2F27CAF2
E:   +7, S = 1 (+), N =  7, M = 20 12 09 13 21 22 19
```

You might or might not be able to see a value `2012-09-13 21:22:19` in there.  Interestingly, this function itself calls on another function in the family, `dump_decimal()` to print out the decimal value.  One year, I'll upgrade the qualifier print to include the hex version, which is a lot easier to read (3594 is 0x0E0A, which is readily understandable by those in the know as 14 digits (E), starting with YEAR (the second 0) to second (A), which is certainly not so obvious from the decimal version.  Of course, the information is the in the type string: DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND.  (The decimal format is somewhat inscrutable to the outsider, but pretty clear to an insider who knows there's an exponent (E), a sign (S), a number of (centesimal) digits (N = 7), and the actual digits (M = ...).  Yes, the name `decimal` is strictly a misnomer as it uses a base-100 or centesimal representation.)

The test doesn't produce that level of detail by default, but I simply had to run it with a high-enough level of debugging set (by command line option).  I'd regard that as another valuable feature.

The quietest way of running the tests produces:

```
test.bigintcvasc.......PASS (phases: 4 of 4 run, 4 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 92 run, 89 pass, 3 fail, 3 expected failures)
test.deccvasc..........PASS (phases: 4 of 4 run, 4 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 60 run, 60 pass, 0 fail)
test.decround..........PASS (phases: 1 of 1 run, 1 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 89 run, 89 pass, 0 fail)
test.dtcvasc...........PASS (phases: 25 of 25 run, 25 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 97 run, 97 pass, 0 fail)
test.interval..........PASS (phases: 15 of 15 run, 15 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 178 run, 178 pass, 0 fail)
test.intofmtasc........PASS (phases: 2 of 2 run, 2 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 12 run, 8 pass, 4 fail, 4 expected failures)
test.rdtaddinv.........PASS (phases: 3 of 3 run, 3 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 69 run, 69 pass, 0 fail)
test.rdtimestr.........PASS (phases: 1 of 1 run, 1 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 16 run, 16 pass, 0 fail)
test.rdtsub............PASS (phases: 1 of 1 run, 1 pass, 0 fail)(tests: 19 run, 15 pass, 4 fail, 4 expected failures)
```

Each program identifies itself and its status (PASS or FAIL) and summary statistics.  I've been bug hunting and fixing a bug other than the ones I found coincidentally, so there are some 'expected failures'.  That should be a temporary state of affairs; it allows me to claim legitimately that the tests are all passing.  If I wanted more detail, I could run any of the tests, with any of the phases (sub-sets of the tests which are somewhat related, though the 'somewhat' is actually arbitrary), and see the results in full, etc.  As shown, it takes less than a second to run that set of tests.

I find this helpful where there are repetitive calculations - but I've had to calculate or verify the correct answer for every single one of those tests at some point.